# How to include long base64 string in XML written by lxml element factory?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, base64, lxml

I'm using the lxml element factory on Python 3 to create an XML file that contains base64-encoded pdf files. The XML file will be used to import data into a database software, so the schema can not be changed.

When creating the XML file, lxml complains about the length of the base64 string:

```
    article = E.article(
        E.galley(
            E.label('PDF'),
            E.file(
                ET.XML("<embed filename=\"" + row['galley'] + ".pdf\"" 
                                            + " encoding=\"base64\" mime_type=\"application/pdf\" >" 
                                            + str(base64fulltext)
                                            + "</embed>")
            ), self.LOCALE(row['language']),
        ), self.LANGUAGE(row['language'])
    )
```

When running the whole script, the error message ('line 45') points to the line where it says `str(base64fulltext)` in the code snippet above. The error message is as follows:

```
(lxml) vboxadmin@linux-x3el:~/repos/x> python3 test-csvFileImport.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-csvFileImport.py", line 65, in <module>
    articlePdfBase64)
  File "/home/vboxadmin/repos/x/y/writer.py", line 45, in exportArticle
    + "</embed>")
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3192, in lxml.etree.XML
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1876, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1757, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1067, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 639, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node, line 1, column 10027189
```

The expected result would have been to have the base64 string to be written to the xml file.

So far, I could only find that there is the option "huge_tree" in lxml.etree.iterparse (http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.iterparse-class.html), but I am not sure whether/how I can use this to solve my problem.

As a workaround, I am considering using string replace to insert the base64 string to the xml after it has been written to file. However, I would be more happy to use a proper lxml solution if anyone could suggest one. Thanks!

Comment: In the meantime, I have noticed that the `lxml.etree._BaseParser` also has an option `huge_tree` (http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.ETCompatXMLParser-class.html). However, I am not sure where to set this, as I am not initializing the BaseParser directly.